# kill all process greater than some process ID and match with particular name

Tags: 12.04, process

I want to kill all google chrome process which is run via CRON.

```
*/5 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && google-chrome --app=http://localhost/runmysql.html
```

so the process which has lower process id I want to keep, and greater than that I want to kill which run via CRON and which has higher process id then initial.

I know how to kill all process

```
sudo killall -9 chorme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the PIDs of the processes:

```
pgrep google-chrome
```

To kill all the google-chrome processes with PIDs greater than say, 4500:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep google-chrome | awk '$1>4500')
```

Example output:

```
ron@ron:~$ pgrep sleep 
3956
4656
4978
4992
ron@ron:~$ kill -9 $(pgrep sleep | awk '$1>4500')
[2]   Killed                  sleep 1000
[3]-  Killed                  sleep 4500
[4]+  Killed                  sleep 6000
roronn@4736Z:~$ pgrep sleep
3956
```

Comment: it works exactly I wanted, but it did not remove google chrome window, you can view https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6G-N1d0zDJeQ1dCNGNiWTRfbG8/view